# Introducción de contraseña al instalar un paquete durante la construcción de un contenedor

Tags: docker, debian

Estoy intentando generar una imagen usando `docker build`.

Tengo mi `Dockerfile`, en el que parto de una imagen de ubuntu, y pretendo añadirle el paquete `slapd`.

El problema surge durante el proceso de instalación **dentro del contenedor**. En un momento dado, el sistema de paquetes **me solicita una contraseña**. Al llegar a ese punto, la ejecución de `docker build` termina con un código de salida `100`.

Encontré esta pregunta en StackOverflow: [Install MySQL on Ubuntu without a password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7739645/8663418). Siguiendo sus respuestas, generé el siguiente `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /
RUN debconf-set-selections <<< 'slapd slapd/internal/adminpw password XXXX'
RUN debconf-set-selections <<< 'slapd slapd/internal/adminpw_again password XXXX'
RUN [ "apt-get", "update" ]
RUN [ "apt-get", "install", "--no-install-recommends", "-y", "slapd" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/etc/init.d/slapd", "start" ]
EXPOSE 389/tcp
EXPOSE 389/udp
```

Sin embargo, al hacer `docker build`, me generó el siguiente error:

> /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Intenté con comillas dobles (`"`) y también sin comillas, y en todos los casos obtuve el mismo error.

¿ Como puedo introducir una contraseña durante la instalación de un paquete dentro del contenedor durante el proceso de construcción ?

Comment: El error dice que esta en la primera linea. yo cambiaria "FROM ubuntu" por "FROM ubuntu:latest"

Comment: Y esta la forma de instalar paquetes : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.utf8

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu

Comment: @Alexmaister Gracias pero no me sirve. El problema es la instalación de `slapd`. **Ese** paquete en concreto. Todo lo demás funciona fino. Pero al instalar ese paquete, `apt-get` (bueno, `debconf`) hace preguntas. Preguntas que no pueden ser respondidas, porque no hay una TTY conectada con `debconf` ni forma de interactuar con el.

Answer (score 0):

Estuvé investigando un poco. De esta forma ya no pide contraseña de forma interactiva.
Añadiendo `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=nointeractive`  y cambiando `<<<` por `<<`.

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /
RUN [ "apt-get", "update" ]
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y slapd
RUN debconf-set-selections << 'slapd slapd/internal/adminpw password pass'
RUN debconf-set-selections << 'slapd slapd/internal/adminpw_again password pass'
ENTRYPOINT [ "/etc/init.d/slapd", "start" ]
EXPOSE 389/tcp
EXPOSE 389/udp
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: No, no sirve. Sigue pidiendo contraseña **durante la instalación** del paquete, y no hay forma de introducirla. Osea, la puedes introducir (y se muestra a todo el mundo), pero no reconoce la pulsación de la tecla `Enter`.

Comment: @Trauma estuve investigando para que cogiese la contraseña "pass" sin interacción con el usuario pero no hubo manera.

Comment: Jejeje ... ya has notado el porqué de mi pregunta :-)

Comment: @Trauma, creo que resolví el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Quizá puedas usar `slappasswd` con el flag `-s`

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y slapd 

EXPOSE 389/tcp
EXPOSE 389/udp

CMD slappasswd -s pass; service slapd start
```